# Get subdomain in MVC for internationalization

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC site that will have multiple translations. We are looking to do that through subdomains like `http://en.domain.com` or `http://fr.domain.com`. We also want to support the regular domain `http://domain.com`.

The translations are working provided that you change the subdomain manually, but I'm looking for a way to automate this and maintain the entire current URL to allow a user who finds `http://en.domain.com/product` to click the link and get another language version of the same page. It seems simple to just isolate the subdomain if it exists, strip it from the current url, and replace with the language version specified.

In essence:

`http://en.domain.com/product` (original)

`http://domain.com/product` (cleaned)

`http://fr.domain.com/product` or `http://de.domain.com/product` etc... (output)

I started out looking for built in functionality like `Request.Url.Subdomain` but have concluded there is no such magical creature. I then moved on to basic string manipulation, but it seemed really convuluted so I set off to find a regex solution.

I've tested this regex with some online regex testers that normally work for me and they are identifying correctly the subdomain when it exists, but fails to find a result when the code actually runs.

I only use regular expressions a little and I'm hoping there is something really obvious I'm doing wrong here. If there is a better solution I'm open to other implimentations.

**C#**

```
string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; //http://en.domain.com/
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
GroupCollection results = regex.Match(url).Groups;
Group result = results[0];
```

Here is the solution I have for now. Not as elegant as I would like, but for something that ate up way too much time it is now working as intended.

**View**

```
<a href="@Html.Action("ChangeLanguage", new { lang = "en" })">English</a>
<a href="@Html.Action("ChangeLanguage", new { lang = "fr" })">French</a>
```

**Action**

```
    public string ChangeLanguage(string controller, string lang)
    {
        string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:https*://)?.*?\.(?=[^/]*\..{2,5})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        GroupCollection results = regex.Match(url).Groups;
        Group result = results[0];
        if (result.Success)
        {
            string[] resultParts = result.Value.Split('/');
            string newSubDomain = resultParts[0] + "//" + lang + ".";
            url = url.Replace(result.Value, newSubDomain);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] urlParts = url.Split('/');
            string oldParts = urlParts[0] + "//";
            string newParts = urlParts[0] + "//" + lang + ".";
            url = url.Replace(oldParts, newParts);
        }


        return url;
    }
```

Comment: Obvious thing: you need no regex delimiters in C#. Try `@"(?:https*://)?.*?\.(?=[^/]*\..{2,5})`.

Comment: Have you considered using something other than subdomains? `http://domain.com/fr/product` works just as well, and doesn't require each new "translation" to be registered as a DNS entry.

Comment: @stribizhev That was it. I'm not 100% sure why the middle part works, but it seems to from testing.

Comment: We have gone the `domain.com/en/etc...` in the past which carries another set of complications so we wanted to explore some other options.

Comment: @Locke125: Does DVK's answer work for you? It looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom routing to make it simple

```
routes.Add("LanguageRoute", new DomainRoute( 
"{language}.example.com/{controller}/{action}", // Domain with parameters 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters 
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
```

))

And get the language value on controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

a useful link may help to you: http://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: This is the type of solution I would like to use, but I don't quite understand the usage of the RouteBase override in the link because I can see that it is running and updating the route, but it is happening after the action runs so the action parameter is always null. I'm assuming it has something to do with the GetVirtualPath method that remains to be implemented, but haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: Hey Locke i've just sampled the code as basic usage. I need to sleep but i will give you a working example with edit tomorrow. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Sure, that is more than I could really ask for. In the mean time I'm going to  keep trying.

Comment: A little bit more info on this. I'm using MVC 5 attribute routing and I'm getting the picture that it isn't the best idea to mix these two things. It can probably be done, but it seems like the implementation might be tricky.

Comment: Normally you can register your normal route parameters after mapping attribute routing on register routes method. But we need to implement DomainRoute class to register subdomains in my method. Since i don't have a working example that have mixed up two situation, i can't help you for now. (A little bit tricky question is: How to mix up filtering and routing. I know most well structured solutions using both to serve localization.(eg. nopCommerce, Umbraco)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like the following (psuedocode - should add safety checks and such):

```
Uri myHost = new Uri("https://en.mydomain.com");
string hostname = myHost.Host; // returns en.mydomain.com
string subdomain = string.split(".", hostname)[0]; // subdomain = "en"
```

This will get the hostname, which you can then split on the "." to an array, and take the first element.

EDIT: Link to MSDN docs on Uri.Host

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is essentially what I was trying at first, but I need a solution that doesn't require a "magic string" domain to be input. It is a fairly common thing for someone in a marketing position somewhere to publish a URL with printed or legal material and just "pick" a domain for it. This means we often have no choice but to support multiple domains for the same site.

Comment: This doesn't require any magic strings at all.  The Uri constructor parameter in the example could come from anything, including a request property, config file, etc.  I just used a literal there for brevity.  The important part is that the Uri.Host property returns the domain name without the other "stuff" in it, and if, by convention, the language is always first, then you can split on the period and take the first element, or search the array for a pattern.  Marketing people have an amazing ability to break any code, regardless of how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar on one of my projects, and this is how I get the current subdomain:

```
string GetSubDomain(Uri url, string defaultValue)
{
    string subdomain = defaultValue;

    if (url.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
    {
        string host = url.Host;
        if (host.Split('.').Length > 2)
        {
            int index = host.IndexOf(".");
            int lastIndex = host.LastIndexOf(".");
            subdomain = index.Equals(lastIndex) ? defaultValue : host.Substring(0, index);
        }
    }

    return subdomain;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
var subdomain = GetSubDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, "en");
```

This assumes that you only ever want the first subdomain in the current URL, so both `http://fr.example.com` and `http://fr.something.example.com` would yield `fr`, whereas `http://example.com` would yield `en` (the default value in this example).